# How to wrap hb.h wrap with cython

Tags: python, cython, harfbuzz

I am writing a wrapper for [hb.h](https://github.com/behdad/harfbuzz/blob/master/src/hb.h) and require `hb_buffer_create()`,`hb_buffer_add_utf8()`,`hb_shape()` and many other to be used in python code.But this file only contains other include files.Should i extern those header files also or i only write the require items under extern of hb.h.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to include `hb.h` but you must make sure that the compiler can find the `.h` files. If they are not located in the standard system location, you can add the `-I` flag to the cython command or the `include_path` option to the cythonize command. http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html

Comment: i want to wrap hb_buffer_create(),hb_buffer_add_utf8(),hb_shape() so i go like this `cdef extern from hb.h:` and below it all the functions?but they are not in hb.h,in fact in other file.Can you illustrate it with the code?

Comment: Can you try it instead with `cdef extern from "hb.h":` and all the functions as you suggest?